# ormLite createOrUpdate depends of 2 values in table

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, overriding, ormlite

I want to override `createOrUpdate` function in ORMLite, that it is depen on two value: `group_id` and `type`. What I want to obtain:

scenario:
In database I have object Model1 and the `group_id`=1 and `type`=small

1. Want to add Model2 with `group_id`=1 and `type`=small - update record
2. Want to add Model23 with `group_id`=1 and `type`=big - create new record

When I made additional field id and set it to generatedID, I allways adding to database but setting  `group_id` to id is not a good idea.

I suppose I need to override `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`class but I dont know where and how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ohibernate instead of ORMlite

https://github.com/10uroi/OHibernate